# Where are the database project and item templates in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I asked this question about VS2010, because the location changed from where it was in VS2008, and I couldn't find it.

Now they've done it AGAIN!!!

So where is it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why have they done this again?  Apparently just to keep us on our toes.  Remember that it was under a folder in Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 called VSTSDB?  Well, that folder still exists in VS2012, but it is now vestigial.  You have to look in another place.  In fact it seems to have been migrated back to where it was in an earlier version of Visual Studio.  Look here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\Items
```

Talk about a convoluted path.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: This is because the DB stuff was completely redone in 2012.  Templates for other project types did not move.

Comment: @SLaks:  Duh!  Really?  Talk about a tautology.  They've changed it every version.  VS2005 it was in Common7\Tools\Templates\Database Project Items.  VS2008 it was in the same place.  VS2010 it was moved to VSTSDB\Extensions\SqlServer\Items.  And now its back in Common7.  What will VS2014 bring?  Stay tuned.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin: when you ask a question you will notice a checkbox for "Answer your own question" -- so it's easy to answer your own question in the same minute.  It's either that or be a VERY fast typist!